# Does struct padding affect unions with arrays?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

If I have something like this:

```
union Colour {
  struct {
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
  };
  int col[3];
};
```

will they take up the exact same space? So if I filled out col[3], then could I also access the array with r, g, and b (col[0], col[1], col[2])? Would the structure be padded in anyway? If not, how would I get it to work?

Comment: It's implementation defined though it will work pretty much everywhere.

Comment: @tstanisl so, the struct could be padded?

Comment: Yes, it could be padded. But padding is never allowed at the beginning of struct/union. Moreover, there are implementation defined layout rules that generally disallow implicit padding between members of the same type. Thus the struct could only be padded at *ending* for practical implementations